# How to import data from external file into my program

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement page replacement algorithm in FIFO-manner.

Since it seems like input has to be thousands of integers at least so i made it 
in text-formatted file
(ex. tr.inp / 1 20 603 20 26000 2401 201 20 603 ...) but i got an issue here... i don't know how to import those numbers into my program so that FIFO algorithm can read them and figure out how many page faults are made. I tried to pull this off with way of getting arguments in argc, argv in main() but no further. I marked in code where i spent most of my time in code to solve it.  What can I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 500000

int fifo();

int refArr[MAX_SIZE];
int str[10];
int tmp[10];
char *chk;
int pgFault_number;
int i, j;
FILE *fp;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if(argc!=2)
        {
                perror("<Usage> $fifo file_name.ip");
                exit(1);
        }

        fp=fopen(&argv[1], "rt");
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
          perror("An error occured while opening the file...");
          exit(1);
        }
       //From here
       while(1)
        {
          chk=fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp);
          if(chk==NULL)
                break;
          str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';

          str
       //To here

        pgFault_number=fifo();

        printf("\n no of page faults is : %d",pgFault_number);

        fclose(fp);

        return 0;
}

int fifo(integers from text file..)
{
      TBD
}

<This is the contents of file> there're 50,000 integers in file.
...
1624
1624
1625
1625
1626
1626
1627
1627
1628
1628
1629
1629
1024
1025
1630
1630
896
897
1631
1631
768
769
640
641
1632
1632
512
513
128
129
384
385
...
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what your actual question is. Do you want to know how you can read all integers from the file without knowing how many there are in advance? And how does your file look like exactly? Could you please post an excerpt verbatim, i.e. using the {code} style?

Comment: @MOehm sorry if i confused you. what i want to know is how i can get all integers from the file(i got 50K integers in text file.)and use them literally.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want `fscanf` and/or `atoi`. I keep a tab open to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `fscanf` instead of `fgets` to automatically get integer values from the file without worrying about the temporary string buffer.

```
int read_value = 0, read_count = 0, pgFault_number = 0;

while(1)
{
  read_count = fscanf(fp, "%d", &read_value);
  if(read_count==EOF)
    break;
  refArr[pgFault_number++] = read_value;
}
```

Then the count of numbers is already stored in `pgFault_number`.

Comment: thank you for your help. After i figured it out with your comments it seems like i was lack of efforts to search... what a shame. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Since you have many integers to read and don't know in advance how many, I suggest allocating storage for the list of integers dynamically. Your input seems to be unformatted, so Austin Mullins's suggestion to use `fscanf` is good.

Here's a function that reads integers from a file with the given filename. It returns a newly allocated array of integers and writes its length to `*len` if it is given:

```
int *read_ints_new(const char *fn, int *len)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(fn, "r");
    int *arr = NULL;
    int size = 0;
    int n = 0;

    if (f == NULL) return NULL;

    for (;;) {
        int res, x = 0;

        res = fscanf(f, "%d", &x);

        if (res == EOF) break;
        if (res == 0) fscanf(f, "%*s");
        if (res == 1) {
            if (n >= size) {
                size = size ? 2 * size : 64;
                arr = realloc(arr, size * sizeof(*arr));
                if (arr == NULL) {
                    n = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            arr[n++] = x;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);

    arr = realloc(arr, n * sizeof(*arr));

    if (len) *len = n;
    return arr;
}
```

The function allocates successively greater chunks of memory, so that all integers that were read will fit. At the end, the exact amount of memory needed is allocated in oder not to waste space.

The `fscanf` tries to parse and convert integer. If it succeeds, it returns 1, i.e the number of conversions made. If it reaches the end of the file, it returns `EOF`. If there is a parsing error (because the next word of data was not an integer), it returns 0 and resets the file pointer to where it left before trying to parse a number. Therefore, we must eat up the next word (without storing it, that's what the asterisk in ´%*s` is for) in oder to skip non-numeric entries.

You can use this function like so:

```
int *array;
int n, i;

array = read_ints_new("file.txt", &n);
if (array == NULL) return 1;

printf("%d entries:\n", n);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i) printf(", ");
    printf("%d", array[i]);
}
printf("\n");

free(array);
```

Remember to release the allocated array with `free` after using it.

Comment: Thank you for your complementary comments for my stuff which had definitely given some ideas. With you materials i let myself mull over for sometime.